# How to include the bit in json while converting json to dataset

Tags: json, .net-core, dataset

In my Dot Net Core Web project I have to dump the Json data to the the Database.

My json data is as follows

```
{
    'FactTable': 'TranMast', 
    'LastCdt':'2018-03-01 01:19:17 pm',
    'DigiAgentDetId':'12',
    'DigiAgentId':'34',
    'LastSeqNo':'23',
    'Deleted':'1',
    'DataSet':{                                                            
        'TranDet':[
             {'Id':'1','TranMastId':'53_25','AcMastId':'sdsd','Account':'sdsd','Amount':'23000','MemName':'dsds','LocId':'ewsds','PartyMastId':'dsdsd','PartyMemId':'23232','AcParentId':'dsdsd','Deleted':'1'},
             {'Id':'2','TranMastId':'53_25','AcMastId':'sdsd','Account':'sdsd','Amount':'24000','MemName':'dsds','LocId':'ewsds','PartyMastId':'dsdsd','PartyMemId':'23232','AcParentId':'dsdsd','Deleted':'1'},
             {'Id':'3','TranMastId':'53_25','AcMastId':'sdsd','Account':'sdsd','Amount':'25000','MemName':'dsds','LocId':'ewsds','PartyMastId':'dsdsd','PartyMemId':'23232','AcParentId':'dsdsd','Deleted':'1'}
        ]
    }
}
```

I am construting above json to dataset as following

```
  var myUtil = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyTableUtilClass>(json);
```

Where MyTableUtilClass have the follwing structure

```
public class MyTableUtilClass
{
    public string LastCdt { get; set; }
    public string DigiAgentId { get; set; }
    public string DigiAgentDetId { get; set; }
    public string LastSeqNo { get; set; }
    public string FactTable { get; set; }
    public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }
}
```

While trying to dump the table in the dataset to the database. in follwing code i am getting the error

```
int result = adapter.Update(table);
```

The Error I Am getting is

```
Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Boolean
```

I know the couse of the problem is the field name Deleted is of type bit.

Then in which format i have to include the bit data in the json string.

Comment: Try more like numeric: `'Deleted':1` instead putting the 1 or 0 inside of a string. Or try writing it as a boolean (because really that's what it is representing: `'Deleted':true`). P.S. strictly what you showed is not valid JSON - property names and strings must be surrounded by _double_ quotes (not single quotes) in compliant JSON. Luckily, your de-serialiser is kind to you and tolerates the mistake, but other software might not accept it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , but i am not able to insert value inside the bit field

Comment: What happens when you try each of my examples? If you still get errors please explain exactly what you see. Thanks

Comment: When i tried 'Deleted':1 the datatype in the dataset for the deleted field is Int16. so gets error like Failed to convert parameter value from a Int to a Boolean

Comment: and the second suggestion?